# differences between libgfortran.3 and libgfortran

Tags: fortran, libraries, dynamic-linking

What is the difference between `libgfortran.3` and `libgfortran`? Are they interchangeable? I am running into a `Internal Error: list_formatted_write(): Bad type` error including a packaged `libgfortran.3` library, and I want to be aware of the potential consequences of switching to gcc's `libgfortran`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no difference, and for typical installations both of those files are symlinks to the actual library, e.g. `libgfortran.so.3.0.0`.

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.1.0/libgfortran.so -> libgfortran.so.3.0.0*
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.1.0/libgfortran.so.3 -> libgfortran.so.3.0.0*
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.1.0/libgfortran.so.3.0.0*
```

The only differences you might encounter are if you are using a libgfortran that doesn't match your gfortran version, but in theory they should all be api compatible since they carry same shared object version.

Comment: Why do these different names even exist?

Comment: @kilojoules Some libraries will have multiple versions installed side by side. The naming lets you choose to link the default version, a specific major version or a specific subversioned library. This is the typical way all libraries on linux are handled.